# Is there only one transport type for MojoX::Session?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Is there only one transport type for [MojoX::Session](https://www.metacpan.org/module/MojoX%3a%3aSession), [MojoX::Session::Transport::Cookie](https://www.metacpan.org/module/MojoX%3a%3aSession%3a%3aTransport%3a%3aCookie)? I could not find any other transport type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, it looks like there is only one derived class for [MojoX::Session::Transport](https://www.metacpan.org/module/MojoX%3a%3aSession%3a%3aTransport%3a%3aCookie). Why do you need a different transport type? There'll be another one when you create what you need and upload it to CPAN.

Comment: You wouldn't need to upload it to CPAN; having a base class which can be subclassed by users is very common...